# PHP gettext does not translate

Tags: php, apache, translation, gettext

I am trying to translate my PHP project using gettext, but it does not work. PHP output gettext string names and not the actual translation.
.po files compiled in POeditor.

Setting locale:

```
// $language = 'en';
// $domain is the same as .mo file name
putenv("LANG=" . $language);
putenv("LANGUAGE=" . $language);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language); // Also tried with .utf8 at the end
bindtextdomain($domain, 'locale'); // Also tried full path
textdomain($domain);
```

PO file: (in locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/filename.po)

```
msgid "SETUP_UI"
msgstr "User Interface"

msgid "SETUP_ACCOUNT"
msgstr "Account and Login"

... and so on
```

Echoing in PHP:

```
<?= gettext('SETUP_UI') ?>
```

Yes, I tried everything from stackoverflow - Googling for more than 3 hours. I have gettext installed in PHP, also tried to restart Apache, recompile .po files...

The result in browser is:

```
SETUP_UI
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile your `.po` files to `.mo` (which is what `gettext` consumes)

Comment: Yes, I know, but POeditor is compiling while saving files.

Comment: @SamuelIllo Are the .mo files in the same locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/ folder?

Comment: Yes, they were in the same folder...but I actually solved the problem by using json files instead of gettext. Maybe also POedit compiler was corrupted or something...

Comment: @SamuelIllo Nah, that literally never happens.